# API Gateway to allow requests from both a VPC Endpoint OR Source IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have a private API Gateway that can only be accessed via a VPC Endpoint.
I want the Resource Policy to only allow requests in if the request is either through the

A - VPC Endpoint (e.g. a Lambda that is within the same VPC)

OR

B - Not within the VPC, but from an external set of IP addresses/CIDR blocks.

I know A can be achieved with:

```
"Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
             "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-xyz"
       }
}
```

I know B can be achieved with:

```
"Condition": {
       "IpAddress": {
             "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx/32"
             ]
       }
}
```

Is it possible however to apply them both, in an OR style manner?
The IP addresses/CIDR blocks are permitted on the VPC's inbound rules.
Lambda's within the same VPC can access the private API gateway.

Thanks

Edit - Full example of the policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:x:y/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-123"
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1234",
                        "1234"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. You need **two IAM statements** to obtain `OR`.
So basically the second statement is exactly same as first one, except the condition. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:x:y/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-123"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:x:y/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1234",
                        "1234"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding two conditions on the API Gateway's Resource Policy results in: "Invalid policy document.", however whilst adding two statements in a single condition is valid it does not seem to be producing the expected "OR" behaviour.

Comment: @Kyanite You would have to provide full example of your policy. Its difficult to speculate why it does not work if you are not going to share it with full error message.

Comment: I've edited the OP with an example of the policy in its current state. If I put two "Condition" statements as your answer suggests, the error message is literally "Invalid policy document." returned in the AWS Console.

Comment: @Kyanite Your policy is only one statement, you must have two statements.

Comment: @Kyanite I updated the answer how it should look like.